# Fruit flavour profile

Tags: fruit

Does anyone know of where can I find the flavour profile of most known fruits?Something like blueberry is a sweet-tart fruit as well as raspberry,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  [this .pdf on fona.com](http://www.fona.com/sites/default/files/discover-fona/FlavorDescriptors_DiscoverFONA.pdf)  about flavor profiles:

> Everyone working to create a new flavor needs to have a common understanding of the desired flavor profile and the flavors they taste during its creation. This can be difficult since everyone’s perception, expectations and experiences are different. That’s why using words called flavor descriptors is so important to the flavor development process.

Follow the link to the .pdf for a list of flavor descriptors for many fruits and related items.